# How to calculate x percentage of column using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate x percentage of column value using pd.Series. I am getting error of NoneType.  Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
def PctMA(self, df, pct):
    pctName = 'PCT' + str(pct)
    pctDecimal = float(pct/100)
    pctCalulated = pd.Series((df['value'] - (df['value'] * pctDecimal)), name = pctName)
    df = df.join(pctCalulated)
    return df
```

```
I get the below error when I execute the code.

    pctCalulated = pd.Series((df['value'] - (df['value'] * pctDecimal)), name = pctName)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Below is the Expected results with Pct1 being generated as 1% column of value.

```
index   value   pct1
1   2476    2451.24
2   2475    2450.25
3   2486    2461.14
4   2536    2510.64
5   2453    2428.47
6   2486    2461.14
7   2648    2621.52
8   2563    2537.37
9   2756    2728.44
```

Comment: how do you use `PctMA()`? If you expect it return something, you missed the return statement. If you expect it modifies `df` for you, it does not.

Comment: Its nice that you posted your expected output. Now, can you provide the input that generated it?

Comment: @adrtam sorry return statement didn't print.

Comment: @RafaelC I updated the error message I get.

Comment: did you by any chance made `pd` to become `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is not in the function but in the input, as I just used your code and it is working:

```
def PctMA(df, pct):
    pctName = 'PCT' + str(pct)
    pctDecimal = float(pct/100)
    pctCalulated = pd.Series((df['value'] - (df['value'] * pctDecimal)), name = pctName)
    df = df.join(pctCalulated)

    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [2476,2476,2486,2536]})
df_1 = PctMA(df, pct)
df_1
```

[image]

It is better to give more details.

Comment: Ok.. so I posted part of the data, so its possible that the error is  in data.  Thanks for you help. let me try portion.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code with minimal changes (just to map with 1% value). below is the code i executed, it is working absolutely fine. Issue with your input.

[image]